# asp.net api route not working correctly keeps showing This page isnt working

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am working on a simple task for asp.net using API's I am quite new to them and still learning. After making a new controller with a route I keep getting the following error:

This page isn’t working

and it asks me to reload. Here is my controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DbService.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/owner/")]
    public class OwnerController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<OwnerController> _logger;
        private readonly PetLicensingContext _context;

        public OwnerController(ILogger<OwnerController> logger, PetLicensingContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }
        // GET: Owner
        [Route("list")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting all breeds");
            var owners = _context.Owners;
            return Ok(owners);
        }



        // POST: Owner/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("create")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Owner owner = new Owner
            {
                Address = "mock address",
                FirstName = "mock firstname",
                LastName = "mock lastname",
                Id = "mock id",
                Pets = "mock pet",
                ownershipDate = DateTime.Now
                
            };
            _context.Owners.Add(owner);
            _context.SaveChanges(); 
            return Ok(owner); 
        }

    }
}
```

I try to access my route in my url as localhost/api/owner/create and that is where it fails. I can't seem to figure out where I am wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are you trying to access the URL? Are you able to debug the code inside `create()` action?

Comment: @Chetan im accessing the url through the browser

Comment: `Create` is a post action. When you try to access from browser, browser will do GET to that URL. That's why you are getting this error. POST URLs should be accessed with POST verb using some REST client such as PostMan.

Comment: Also you have `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` on top of your action. This means that you need to pass the antiForgerToken also when you call this action. If your intention to use this as Web API you should not use `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`.